# Eval not working with linux makefile

Tags: linux, perl, shell, makefile, centos

I am trying to automate the generation of php files of symfony.

I am reading the data from text file and then trying to insert that into the command

This is my code in make file

```
MYFILE = document.txt
READ_ENTITY=eval `perl -plne '$$\ = " "' $(MYFILE)`

FIELDS = $(call READ_ENTITY)
mytest:
    commands --fields="$(FIELDS)"
```

basically `document.txt` is field config in separate lines. First i am joing all the lines with space using perl and then i want to have the output of perl in variable `fields`. which i want to insert in command

Comment: You are not using the full power of the `-l` switch. With that, you can specify the output record separator as an octal number, so that your one-liner comes simply: `perl -l040 -pwe0 $(MYFILE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is [`$(shell...)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html)

```
READ_ENTITY:=$(shell perl -plne '$$\ = " "' $(MYFILE))
```

I suggest using the `:=` assignment so that the evaluation is done only once. Otherwise, a shell will be spawned each time `READ_ENTITY` is evaluated. (See the [documentation](http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/make-3.79/html_chapter/make_6.html#SEC59) about this.)

Backticks are not special in make's syntax. The following

```
FOO=`ls`
```

will just assign the string `` "`ls`" `` to the variable `FOO`.

It is unclear to me what you are expecting the `$(call READ_ENTITY)` bit to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have tilde misplaced here. Try this:

```
READ_ENTITY=`eval perl -plne '$$\ = " "' $(MYFILE)`
```

Comment: Do you really need to use both eval and backticks?

Comment: backtick is for command substitution and eval is for bash eval command. I believe `READ_ENTITY=\`perl -plne '$$\ = " "' $(MYFILE)\`` may also work.

Comment: I suppose it depends on whether the output of the Perl command is another command that should be evaluated.